# freestyle no working on mesh

Tags: freestyle, error

[image]My question is rather simple: why won’t rendering with freestyle work on my mesh. I have checked my preferences. Also I can’t find any fault on my mesh, although I suspect that is where the problem lies. I just can’t figur out where to look.

please?

PS. The blender file is here: [image]

DS. What I want is for all the lines in the picture (in wire frame mode) above to be rendered with free style lines.

Comment: Can you explain what you are not satisfied with? Isn't freestyle tracing the lines? All or some of them? Please add some picture describing the issue in your question

Comment: no problem with the file its render in freestyle look the result http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=120212

Comment: Ok. I chose render preview and the lines didn't show there. When I render properly they do show. But the issue now is that freestyle only tracks the outer contour but not the lines of the arms. How do you fix that?